# Probability of passing an exam with question tickets

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 15 exam tickets and each has 2 questions.A student can answer 25 questions from total 15x2=30 questions.What is the probability for him to pass his exam if in order to pass his exam he must : answer both questions of a ticket OR answer correctly one of the two questions on a ticket and then answer correctly a random question from a different ticket? Assume that picking a question on a ticket is $\frac{1}{2}$.

What I have tried : There is some-kind of conditional probability . Let $H_{k}$ for k=0,1,2 be there are exactly k tickets for which the student doesn't know any of the questions and A be the event - the student takes the exam, but I don't know how to continue calculating the probability.

Comment: Could you edit into your question what you have tried?

Comment: @Henry i have edited the question with what I have tried

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- What is the probability the student knows the answer to the first question asked and then knows the answer to the second question asked?
- What is the probability the student knows the answer to the first question asked and then does not know the answer to the second question asked and then knows the answer to the third question asked?
- What is the probability the student does not know the answer to the first question asked and then knows the answer to the second question asked and then knows the answer to the third question asked?
- Add these mutually exclusive probabilities together